# How do I allow users to enlarge or decrease the size of a html table?

Tags: jquery, function, text, interactive

Well Im working on a little sound board project and I added a thing to create the website more
dynamic

When you click increase/decrease it increases/descreases the text size in the buttons.
Unfortunately its useless unless it includes a table resize and also a button resize.

Here is the code in action: http://serverbc.ucoz.com/main.html 
SCROLL TO THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE TO SEE THE BUTTONS!

What do I need to add for it to work nicely?

BTW! Here is the code for how I did the text:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">       
    </script>
    <div id="box1">
    <font color=white>rrrr</font>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".increaseFont,.decreaseFont").click(function(){
     var type=  $(this).val();
      var curFontSize = $('#box1').css('font-size');
      if(type=='increase'){
       $('#box1').css('font-size', parseInt(curFontSize)+1);
       }
     else{
       $('#box1').css('font-size', parseInt(curFontSize)-1);
      }
        });
    });
    </script>


    <div><input type="button" value="increase" class="increaseFont"></input></div>
    <div><input type="button" value="decrease" class="decreaseFont"></input></div>
```

Comment: Your CSS has your table as a fixed width `width: 1050px;`.  You've constrained it so it can't grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using fixed width for your button class `Button`. it won't grow with a fixed width. Remove the width property from `Button` class and try.

:Check this http://jsfiddle.net/akhilrs/qXHKn/